# Interschematic virtual port

Tags: altium

I have some rather simple [Altium](http://www.altium.com/) project, which basically consists of two pcb's:

1. **Audio Signal Input PCB** (*PCB 1*). On this PCB are placed (for now) [RCA Jack](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/209/KC-301054-1171643.pdf) and [Straight JACK](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/704/15K101-40ME4-977140.pdf) pair (one for left, second for right channel):
   [image: Audio Signal Input PCB]
2. **Audio Signal Input Selector PCB** (*PCB 2*). On this PCB there is [relay](http://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g5v2.pdf) for Input Signal Switching:
   [image: Input Switching PCB]
   Now, both PCBs will be connected **not with PCB vias**, but with physical coax cable. How do I designate [Audio Signals Ports](http://www.altium.com/documentation/15.1/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-Port((Port))_AD) on **both PCBs**, so I can connect them in [Top Schematic](http://www.altium.com/documentation/15.1/display/ADES/((Multi-Sheet+and+Multi-Channel+Design))_AD#!Multi-SheetandMulti-ChannelDesign-HierarchicalDesign) with *some kind/version of port*, which is ignored by PCB router? To simplify, I want to **show** the coax cabling connection in schematic, but to ignore it in PCB design phase, because the connections will not be physically on PCB?

Comment: Which version of altium are you using?  They recently added a multi - board schematic which is probably what you want.

Comment: Why don't you put the connector on the schematic...?

Comment: @Selvek I am using AD 16.0.

Comment: @immibis will do ...